# trying to find all digits that are followed by either a whitespace or a dash using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find all digits that are followed by either a whitespace or a dash using regex

Right now hat's what it's look like :

```
import re

txt = "123 4 56-7 maine x1s56"

x = re.findall(r"\d+\s|-\b)", txt)

print(x)
```

Results are :

```
['123 ', '4 ', '-', '7 ']
```

But it should print:

```
['123 ', '4 ', '56', '7 ']
```

Comment: You need `\d+(?:\s|-)` or `\d+[\s\-]`. Then whether or not (and where) to include `\b` depends on other requirements you might have that were not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Try `\d+(?=\s|-|$)`

Comment: You're keeping the space but not the dash. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the expected output, it looks like the space after a number must be kept and the hyphen/minus should not.

In that case, you need to use

```py
import re
txt = "123 4 56-7 maine x1s56"
x = re.findall(r"\d+(?:\s|(?=-))", txt)
print(x) # => ['123 ', '4 ', '56', '7 ']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wt0Fgu).

*Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\s|(?=-))` - a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) that matches

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `|` - or
  - `(?=-)` - a position that is immediately followed with `-`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p4rzMa/1).

Answer (score 0):

The alternation operator (`|`) has the lowest precedence of all regex operators. That is, it tells the regex engine to match either *everything* to the left of the vertical bar or *everything* to the right of the bar.

So the regular expression `r"\d+\s|-\b)"` means (one or more digits followed by a space) OR (a dash followed by a word boundary).

If you want to limit the reach of the alternation, you need to use parentheses for grouping. Or, since you want to alternate between only two characters, you can use a character class instead.

```
import re

txt = "123 4 56-7 maine x1s56"
x = re.findall(r"\d+[\s-]", txt)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['123 ', '4 ', '56-', '7 ']
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the tricky part is that both space and hyphen are part of the match, but only space gets included in the match.  You need the hyphen inside a lookahead but the space outside, something like this:

```
\d+(\s|(?=-))
```